# subclipse change folder in svn repository perspective

Tags: eclipse, svn

I checked out tomcat 6 from http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc6.0.x/trunk which unfortunatly I put as the repository location in subclipse.

It appears that I should have used a parent http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat so I can compare tomcat 6 and tomcat 7 code.

I can't disconnect this location as the project (with changes) is connected in the worspace.

Is there any way to change the location to a parent of the existing location?

**IF THIS QUESTION DOESN'T BELONG ON SO** can it be moved to the appropiate site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a new repository location and compare the files/directories from within the **SVN Repositories** view. (Ctrl+Select für Multi-Selection)